# Community in a Sub-Directory

Tags: community, force.com-sites, customer-community, custom-domain

**Situation**

Companies like IBM serve their community in a sub-directory `https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/?language=en_US`. However, the rest of IBM‘s Website is not based on `Salesforce Communities`.

**Question**

What do I have to do to implement the my community in the same way?

Example: I want to serve `www.mycompany.com` mainly from a self hosted CMS. However, `www.mycompany.com/support` must be served from Salesforce Communities.

Comment: did you ever find out how to do implement this? Looking to solve a similar scenario

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this as a number of clients I have worked at have done this with a specific subdomain within their overall domain. This has been either as a prefix domain, e.g. www.connect.clientdomain.com or a subdomain www.clientdomain.com/connect

Follow these steps

1. You will need to get a get a CNAME record setup for the domain with
   the Salesforce actual URL for the community that ends in .force.com.
   After this is registered then you can get a certificate.
2. Generate Certificate Signing Request from Salesforce to implement
   the community with https:// from the Certification Authority that
   the company uses.
3. Upload the certificate to Salesforce and setup the community to use
   this domain.

Full [SF documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212707&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: Hello Dave, I don't want to serve www.ibm.com from Salesforce. I just want to serve www.ibm.com/mysupport from Salesforce. How can I do that?

Comment: Christian, what we have needed to do is going with a domain like support.ibm.com so it can be registered with the CNAME and get a certificate created because I am not sure if we can create the CNAME to point to a path like www.ibm.com/support.  I'll have to check with my DNS expert on that.

Comment: Hello Dave. IBM did it. If you look atet www.ibm.com/mysupport it is clearly a community. While the rest of ibm.com is not hosted by Salesforce... So it is possible. I just would like to know how...